# App on iPhone simulator doesn't match what's on the iPod touch. (Git Branches)

Tags: iphone

I have three development branches. Ready, Development and TestingGround. I am using XCode's GIT. Each development branch has a unique identifier so that I can run all three on my iPod Touch.

TestingGround builds and runs fine on my iPod Touch. However when I run to test on my iPhone simulator, the build that is running does not match what I have written in code.

The app that is running in the iPhone simulator looks more like the "Development" branch even though I'm switched to the "TestingGround" branch.

It's annoying as I have to build on my iPod Touch to see the changes.

Any ideas how I can fix this? What should I be looking at?

Many thanks,

Ben

Answer (score 0):

reset the contents of simulator each time. i think reseting contents of simulator will work

Answer (score 0):

Also select Clean from the Product menu.

Answer (score 0):

Just to summarize it. Do these 3 steps to clean properly:

**1.** Reset the simulator / delete the app from device
**2.** Press `Cmd + Shift + K` to clean the project
**3.** Press `Cmd + Alt + Shift + K` to clean the build folder

This should give you an absolutely clean build.